# Remove words starting with uppercase

Tags: php

I have a string, for example FastFood, how do I remove Food and leave only first word? Also it could be VeryFastFood, then Very should be left, etc.

Some strings may containt 3 uppercase starting letters. I need then only this 3 letters to be left. for example YOUProblem - must be YOU.

Comment: What if the string is YOUP? What should it be then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a function that can do it for you as well:

```
function removeUppercase($word){
   if(ctype_upper(substr($word,0,3))) //Check for first 3 uppercase and return those
       return substr($word,0,3);
   for($a=1;$a<strlen($word);$a++){ //Otherwise loop through letters until uppercase is found
      if(ctype_upper($word[$a]))
         return substr($word,0,$a);
   }
   return $word;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a hackish solution, first thing I could think of

```
<?php

$string = "VeryFastFood";

$found = false;
$tmp = '';
for($i = 0; $i < strlen($string); ++$i)
{
    $char = $string[$i];
    if(ctype_upper($char))
    {
        if($found)
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            $found = true;
        }
    }
    $tmp .= $char;
}

$string = $tmp;
var_dump($string);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
preg_match(/^[A-Z]([A-Z]{2}|[A-Z][a-zA-Z]|[a-z]{2})[a-z]*/), $stringToCheck, $matches);

$matches[0] //has your string
```

Something like this should work.